# How to find percentage by group in crystal reports?

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports, percentage

I am using crystal reports plugin in visual studio to develop crystal reports.

In my report, there are three group by functions. The hierarchy is shows below -

```
 Employee.EmployeeType
        Employee.EmployeeCity
           Employee.OfficeBranch
```

I need to calculate percentage of Seats occupied in every branch per city. The condition is that only those seats should be considered that have seatnumber greater than 5.

I am using the following formula but it is giving me error saying `) expected` -

@seatNumber

```
if({Employee.SeatNumber},{Employee.OfficeBranch})>5
then
count({Employee.SeatNumber})
else
0
```

I know we have to use `if ({key field}, {Group field})` and then we have to create another formula which we will use to `sum(@seatNumber)`.

and then will have to use both to calculate percentage per group. But I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

if({Employee.SeatNumber},{Employee.OfficeBranch})>5
is not a valid expression.

You probably meant something like:
if {Employee.SeatNumber} > 5

Comment: I want to compare the seat numbers per group. By using ```{Employee.SeatNumber} > 5```, it would compare for all records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to ignore seats 1-to-5 it would be a lot simpler to just add this condition to the record selection formula:

```
{Employee.SeatNumber} > 5
```

Comment: But how would it help to calculate the percentage for seat numbers more than 5 ? I want to do it for every branch per city

Comment: I am referring to this link http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=10618 but the issue is that I have to count the rows based on the condition and for that it is giving me an error in the formula